# XOR neural network error keeps converging to 0.5

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network

I just started attempting to make my own neural network in c# by copying a simple one I found written in python and the output always ends at 0.5. I looked at all other questions posted about this same problem on Google and none of the solutions were applicable. I have no idea why this is happening. Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
public class NeuralNetwork
        {
            private double[,] w;

            public NeuralNetwork()
            {
                w = random(2, 1);
            }

            public double[,] getWeights()
            {
                return w;
            }

            public void train(double[,] x, double[,] y, int iterations)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                {
                    double[,] output = think(x);
                    double[,] error = Mat.subtract(Mat.transpose(y), output);
                    double[,] adjust = dot(Mat.transpose(x), Mat.multiply(error, doSigDeriv(output)));

                    w = Mat.add(w, adjust);
                }
            }

            public double[,] think(double[,] inputs)
            {
                return doSig(dot(inputs, w));
            }

            private double[,] dot(double[,] a, double[,] b)
            {
                double[,] dot = new double[a.GetLength(0), b.GetLength(1)];

                for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < b.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < b.GetLength(0); k++)
                            dot[i, j] += a[i, k] * b[k, j];
                    }
                }
                return dot;
            }

            private double[,] random(int w, int h)
            {
                double[,] a = new double[w, h];
                for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                    {
                        a[i, j] = 2 * (double)rand.NextDouble() - 1;
                    }
                }
                return a;
            }

            private double[,] doSig(double[,] a)
            {
                double[,] b = new double[a.GetLength(0), a.GetLength(1)];
                for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        b[i, j] = sig(a[i, j]);
                    }
                }
                return b;
            }

            private double[,] doSigDeriv(double[,] a)
            {
                double[,] b = new double[a.GetLength(0), a.GetLength(1)];
                for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        b[i, j] = a[i, j] * (1 - a[i, j]);
                    }
                }
                return b;
                //return Mat.multiply(a, Mat.subtract(one(a), a));
            }

            private double sig(double x)
            {
               return 1 / (double)(1 + Math.Exp(-x));
            }
        }
```

x is the array I used for inputs and y for outputs, and Mat is just a class I made to handle the matrix operations. When I tested it, I changed the iterations to 10000 and 50000 and got the same result. Any insight is greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I just realized that when it's supposed to be 0, it's -0.5 and 1 is 0.5.

Comment: I think most people into NN dont code them from ground up anymore, i used to, but i dont do that anymore, you better spend time on pytorch / tensorflow. There you work with a pipeline. input layer hidden layers, output layers learn about RELU etc.
(I think thats time much better spend, if you want to dive into it)

Comment: ahh okay I see, so you think that's more worth it to work with and learn even as a beginner?

Comment: Especially as a beginner it's more rewarding to have a neural net do some actual funny things, recognize cats, go to kaggle.com and try the Titanic problem, learn about it run code from others in the cloud it's free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the comment of user219279 is correct: NN better run in GPU/Tensor nowadays, which is much faster when you are going to scale up your network. For XOR back propagation and study however, you won't need performance.

An output value of 0.5 is very common and called "local minimum". It happens when your network training cannot converge, for some reason. Weights reach giant +/- values instead of a balance with small values and 0/1 outputs.

The error I see above: there are not enough weights. You allocate your weights as a 2x1 array, connecting input output. You can't train a XOR outcome net with only 2 weights. You need at least 5 weights. See for more info on a suitable XOR architecture  http://mnemstudio.org/neural-networks-multilayer-perceptrons.htm

Comment: I'll definitely do this! just read the link, it's very useful. can I add the new weights to the matrix that already exists, or would I need a second matrix for the additional ones? thanks!

Comment: nevermind, i rewrote the middle and utilized 6 weights this time and after a while it works properly now. thanks again!

Comment: The more neurons you put in, the more flexible your training will be, because the weights stay low in value. Network can still learn. On the entry of every neuron there is an S-function that is steep around 0: the weight learns in that range, not beyond ca -3 or 3. If you have too many weights like that the network is saturated. Try this: set up the network in some configuration, train it.. then **change** the traning. See how many cycles it takes to swap your network. A re-training should never get 0.5 results, or take too long.. then you used not enough neurons, or inconsistent training.